# What is the correct syntax for this right join problem?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm working on my homework and am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax for the "NOT IN" functionality.

The database is a small insurance database (carriers, members, employers, plans) made up for this assignment. I am supposed to "List ALL carriers and the count of plans they have. (use either the right or left join). List the carrier_id, carname, and the count of plans."

This is what I have written as of right now:

```
SELECT carrier_id, carname, count(*) AS NoPlans
FROM carriers RIGHT JOIN plans
ON carriers.carrier_id = plans.carrierid;
```

This throws the "not a single-group group function" error when I try to run it, but that's because I think it's looking for a WHERE clause, and I don't know what the condition should be.

Carrier table structure:

```
Name                           Null     Type
------------------------------ -------- -----------
CARRIER_ID                     NOT NULL CHAR(4)
CARNAME                                 CHAR(35)
CARADDRESS                              CHAR(50)
CARCITY                                 CHAR(30)
CARSTCODE                               CHAR(2)
CARZIP                                  CHAR(10)
CARPHONE                                CHAR(10)
CARWEBSITE                              CHAR(255)
CARCONTACTFIRSTNAME                     CHAR(35)
CARCONTACTLASTNAME                      CHAR(35)
CARCONTACTEMAIL                         CHAR(255)

11 rows selected
```

Plans table structure:

```
Name                           Null     Type
------------------------------ -------- -------------
PLANID                         NOT NULL NUMBER
PLNDESCRIPTION                          CHAR(35)
PLNCOST                                 NUMBER(8,2)
CARRIERID                               CHAR(4)

4 rows selected
```

Comment: @Bob: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Jeff, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT carrier_id, carname, count(*) AS NoPlans 
  FROM carriers RIGHT JOIN plans 
    ON carriers.carrier_id = plans.carrierid
 GROUP BY carrier_id, carname;
```

Comment: `noPlans` is going to be a count of the `carname` per carrier, not the number of plans to the carrier.

Comment: @OMG: I suspect the question isn't worded well and this is what's expected; your answer may be a bit advanced? But @Scottie you have the semi-colon in the wrong place, even after @Justin's edit.

Comment: Oops... I just copied and pasted his original query and added the group by.  I forgot to modify the semi-colon.  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

`count` requires a `group by` clause.

You should also consider your join.  It probably isn't doing quite what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.carrier_id, c.carname, count(1) as no_plans
FROM carriers c RIGHT JOIN plans p
ON c.carrier_id = p.carrierid
group by c.carrier_id , c.carname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT carrier_id, carname, count(plans.PLANID) AS NoPlans
FROM carriers LEFT JOIN plans
ON carriers.carrier_id = plans.carrierid
GROUP BY carrier_id, carname
```